# True or False: Continuous function from closed unit disc $D$ to unit circle $S^1$ have a fixed point. NBHM 2012 PhD.

Tags: general-topology, contest-math

I want to check if the statement is true or false. I know Brouwer's fixed point theorem but since $S^1$ is not convex it is not applicable. I can't find a counterexample to this, I feel there is some theorem needed but I am unable to invoke any such theorem. Any help/hint is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your map is so  a continuous map from $D$ into $D$ so it has  fixed point by Brouwer's Thereom.

Comment: Wow, hard time waking up for me here. Sorry for that answer... I am so stupid sometimes. :-(

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy it may sound stupid, but what you said is with codomain D and then we have a fixed point. How can we say the same when the codomain is $S^1$?

Comment: Well, just post-compose with the inclusion $S^1 \to D$.

Comment: thanks @Mathy it worked!